# MPI_Scatter a 2D array in other 2D arrays

Tags: c++, c, multidimensional-array, parallel-processing, mpi

I want to scatter a 2D array in other 2D arrays (one for each process) using this specific way of allocating memory.

```
int (*matrix)[cols] = malloc(sizeof *matrix* rows);
```

I keep getting this error:

> One of the processes started by mpirun has exited with a nonzero exit
> code.  This typically indicates that the process finished in error.
> If your process did not finish in error, be sure to include a "return
> 0" or "exit(0)" in your C code before exiting the application.

> PID 7035 failed on node n0 (127.0.0.1) due to signal 11.

I think the problem is on scatter but I am new to parallel programming so if anyone knows what the issue is please help me.
Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "mpi.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  int my_rank;
  int p;
  int root;
  int rows = 0;
  int cols = 0;
  int **matrix;

  int i, j;
  int local_rows;
  int answer = 0;
  int broke = 0;

  MPI_Init(& argc, & argv);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, & my_rank);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, & p);

  if (my_rank == 0) {

    do {
        printf("Enter Dimensions NxN\n");
        scanf("%d", & rows);
        scanf("%d", & cols);
        if (cols != rows) {
            printf("Columns must be the same as rows,enter dimensions again.\n");
        }
    } while (rows != cols);        
    int (*matrix)[cols] = malloc(sizeof *matrix* rows);

    printf("Fill array %dx%d\n", rows, cols);
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            scanf("%d",&matrix[i][j]);

        }
    }

    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            printf("%d ",matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
  }

  root = 0;
  MPI_Bcast(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  MPI_Bcast(&cols, 1, MPI_INT, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  local_rows = rows / p;


  int (*local_matrix)[rows] = malloc(sizeof *local_matrix* local_rows);

  MPI_Scatter(matrix, local_rows*rows, MPI_INT,local_matrix, local_rows*rows, MPI_INT, 0,   MPI_COMM_WORLD);

  printf("\nLocal matrix fo the process %d is :\n", my_rank);

  for (i = 0; i < local_rows; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        printf("%d ", local_matrix[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  if (my_rank==0){
     free(matrix);
     free(local_matrix);
  }   
  MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you declared two variables with the name matrix:

`int **matrix;`

and

`int (*matrix)[cols] = malloc(sizeof *matrix* rows);`

and since the latter was declared inside the if (my_rank == 0) {..} the variable begin used in the scatter `MPI_Scatter(matrix, local_rows*rows, MPI_INT,local_matrix, local_rows*rows, MPI_INT, 0,   MPI_COMM_WORLD);`

is the first one, the not allocated one, and not the one you allocated space for. That is why you are getting the error.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "mpi.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

int my_rank;
int p;
int root;
int rows = 0;
int cols = 0;

int i, j;
int local_rows;
int answer = 0;
int broke = 0;
MPI_Init(& argc, & argv);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, & my_rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, & p);

int (*matrix)[cols];

if (my_rank == 0) {

    do {
        printf("Enter Dimensions NxN\n");
        scanf("%d", & rows);
        scanf("%d", & cols);
        if (cols != rows) {
            printf("Columns must be the same as rows,enter dimensions again.\n");
        }

    } while (rows != cols);        

    matrix = malloc(sizeof *matrix * rows);

    printf("Fill array %dx%d\n", rows, cols);
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            scanf("%d",&matrix[i][j]);

        }
    }

    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            printf("%d ",matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

root = 0;
MPI_Bcast(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Bcast(&cols, 1, MPI_INT, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
local_rows = rows / p;

// Changed from the original
int (*local_matrix)[cols] = malloc(sizeof *local_matrix* local_rows);

printf("R = (%d, %d, %d) \n",my_rank, local_rows, cols);


if(my_rank == 0)
{
    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            printf("%d ",matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}


MPI_Scatter(matrix, local_rows*cols, MPI_INT,local_matrix, 
            local_rows*cols, MPI_INT, 0,   MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

...

Btw I think you meant:

`int (*local_matrix)[cols] = malloc(sizeof *local_matrix* local_rows);`

and not

`int (*local_matrix)[rows] = malloc(sizeof *local_matrix* local_rows);`

Also do not forget to free the "local_matrix" for the slaves also.